# How to restore deleted data symmetric ds

Tags: postgresql, synchronization, symmetricds

I had postgres and symmetric DS 2.5.8 in two servers. Today the data from one of the table was deleted almost 1000 entries and there is no evidence in the symmetric ds logs. i can see delete event in sym_data.

All I could see is

2018-05-25 14:21:53,864 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-8] Routed 2 data events in 2489 ms
2018-05-25 14:22:18,764 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-19] Routed 4 data events in 2455 ms
2018-05-25 14:22:43,682 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-13] Routed 3 data events in 2465 ms
2018-05-25 14:22:56,178 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-6] Routed 1 data events in 2495 ms
2018-05-25 14:23:21,121 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-2] Routed 4 data events in 2471 ms
2018-05-25 14:23:46,152 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-8] Routed 4 data events in 2494 ms
2018-05-25 14:24:11,104 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-17] Routed 2 data events in 2478 ms
2018-05-25 14:24:23,566 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-7] Routed 2 data events in 2461 ms
2018-05-25 14:24:48,489 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-12] Routed 4 data events in 2460 ms
2018-05-25 14:25:13,415 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-14] Routed 3 data events in 2470 ms
2018-05-25 14:25:25,894 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-16] Routed 2 data events in 2478 ms
2018-05-25 14:25:50,814 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-17] Routed 4 data events in 2465 ms
2018-05-25 14:26:15,755 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-13] Routed 4 data events in 2471 ms
2018-05-25 14:26:40,699 INFO  [SymmetricDS] [SymmetricDS-job-17] Routed 2 data events in 2454 ms

How can i restore the deleted entries ? Also why this happened ?

- Vishnu

Answer (score 1):

Someone or some application deleted the data. Check the columns row_data or old_data if values of the rows are there and transform the CSV to SQL insert statements and insert back the data